# After reinstalling the kernel, the system error has disappeared. Does this mean that everything is OK in the system?

Tags: drivers, kernel, xubuntu

I use Xubuntu 18.04.

I wanted to install an external Wi-Fi adapter, but installing the drivers led to freezes and a system error (`kernel bug in the file ...../dev.c: some string number`). I removed the driver using `apt autoremove --purge package_name`, but the system error continued to appear after the system reboot.

The solution came to mind - reinstall the Linux kernel. I did this with `apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic linux-image-version_number-generic`. After that, the error stopped appearing and everything seems to be working fine, including my internal Wi-Fi adapter.

Does this mean that everything is good and working in the system? Or need to reinstall the system? Is there in Linux any tools to check the system and software health?

I'm sorry if the question is stupid, I'm new. Searched in Google and here, did not find information specifically on my question.

Comment: NJif there are no problems and nothing in the logs you are good to go

Comment: @Panther: That sounds like an answer to me. :-]